# Grails: Integration test crashes with NPE on GORM collection?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, integration-testing, spock

I'm trying to do a fairly simple integration test on a controller, and while it all works in the application, the integration test fails with a NPE. I'm still new to Grails 2.5.0 / Spock testing, and I'm sure I must be doing something stupid here, but can't figure it out. I would assume that in an integration test (unlike a unit test) the behavior should be pretty much the same as when the app is running.

Imagine the following (very simplified) scenario to reproduce the problem I'm getting. A simple 3-level domain object hierarchy:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
    static hasMany = [chapters: Chapter]
}

class Chapter {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [book: Book]
}
```

And a controller with a single action to receive all chapters from all books owned by a single author (i.e. accessing collections 2 levels deep):

```
class AuthorController {
    def listChapters(Long id) {
        Author a = Author.get(id)
        respond a.books.chapters.flatten()
    }
}
```

I have sample data generated in bootstrap, and the above controller method works and returns all chapters from all books by a single author in a flat, 1-level JSON array (as expected). But the integration test crashes with a NPE as if the lazy-loaded collection was never initialized, i.e. `Cannot get property 'chapters' on null object`

Here's the test:

```
class AuthorIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def controller

    def setup() {
        controller = new AuthorController()
    }

    def cleanup() {
        controller = null
    }

    def "chapters of a single author can be retrieved"() {
        when: "I call the listChapters action"
        controller.response.format = 'json'
        controller.request.method = 'GET'
        controller.params.id = 1
        controller.listChapters()

        then: "I get 200 OK"
        controller.response.status == 200
    }
}
```

I'm sure I must be missing something pretty obvious, but have already spent 3 hours on this to no avail. I would appreciate any pointers to why this is crashing or if my way with this integration test is completely wrong?

UPDATE: Here's BootStrap code with sample data:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def rado = new Author(name: 'Rado').save(flush:true)
    def joe = new Author(name: 'Joe').save(flush:true)

    def book1 = new Book(name: 'Book1', author: rado).save(flush:true)
    def book2 = new Book(name: 'Book2', author: rado).save(flush:true)
    def book3 = new Book(name: 'Book3', author: rado).save(flush:true)
    def book4 = new Book(name: 'Book4', author: joe).save(flush:true)

    new Chapter(name: 'Chapter 1', book: book1).save(flush:true)
    new Chapter(name: 'Chapter 2', book: book1).save(flush:true)
    new Chapter(name: 'Chapter 3', book: book1).save(flush:true)
    new Chapter(name: 'Chapter 4', book: book1).save(flush:true)

    new Chapter(name: 'BChapter 1', book: book2).save(flush:true)
    new Chapter(name: 'BChapter 2', book: book2).save(flush:true)
}
```

Comment: Probably a typo, but the action is in the AuthorController, while you are testing UserController.   The test looks fine. Can you please show how you generate the data in bootstrap?  And also try doing `println Author.list()*.books` in the setup of the test to check if the db population worked.

Comment: seeding setup in environments { test { } } in config.groovy? test database setup? Test looks fine other than what Yaro mentioned.

Comment: Does command object binding happen in Integration tests?  I don't use them much, but in my UnitTests, I'd have to call controller.listChapters(1), rather than setting a params and calling the controller without the argument.  I don't have much experience with 2.5.x though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, sorry about the typo User vs. Author - it happened while editing code for SO. I edited my question and also added BootStrap code with sample data.

Comment: @Yaro / @railsdog - the data was initialized properly, I tested on 2 levels - added a logger call to listChapters action with `Book.countByUser(u)` which prints the expected value of 3, and also added `Book.findAllByUser(User.get(1)).each { println it }` to the test's `when` and it prints the books. However, adding `println User.list()*.books` only prints [null, null]

Comment: @BillJames I believe it binds correctly, as the controller action's log messages indicate proper Author is found.

Comment: It looks like the Books know what Author they belong to, but the Author doesn't know about the Books.  What happens if you add the Books to the Author directly?   `rado.addtoBooks(book1)`  , etc?  in your BootStrap code?

Comment: @NancyDeschênes thank you - that was it! I no longer remember what I was trying to address in the actual app (it was 2 years ago and this was just a sample code to demonstrate the same issue - the app has been converted to Grails 3 in the meantime). Would you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?